# Array of Pointers - temporary array being created at the same location which changes the previous saved content value

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, scanf

I am trying to write a program that could take in the input (First Name, Last Name, Score) from the user and print it after taking all the inputs like this.

```
fname1 lname1 : 99
fname2 lname2 : 23
fname3 lname3 : 29
//Note that all of them are input
```

I wrote the following program, it works but prints the last input n times. I know what the problem is but don't know how to solve it. The **temp arrays variable is being created at exactly the same place every time** and it is making all the elements the same. **How to fix it?**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define LENGTH 3

int main() {
    int *score[LENGTH];
    char *fname[LENGTH];
    char *lname[LENGTH];

    for(int i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++){
        printf("Enter name and score of batter %d: ",i);
        char ftemp[10];
        char ltemp[10];
        int tempScore;

        scanf("%s %s %d", ftemp, ltemp, &tempScore);
        fname[i] = ftemp;
        lname[i] = ltemp;
        score[i] = &tempScore;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++){
        printf("%s %s %d\n", fname[i], lname[i], *score[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to copy instead of assign the pointers. See `strncpy` for that.

Comment: That's so wrong. Never use strncpy. And the real problem is that no memory has been allocated.

Comment: @gnasher729  could you please explain in a bit more detail?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to assign a reference to a local variable to score,fname and lname .You can not do that because it destroys when exit from their  scope,instead of try this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define LENGTH 3

int main() {
    int *score[LENGTH];
    char *fname[LENGTH];
    char *lname[LENGTH];

    for(int i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++){
        printf("Enter name and score of batter %d: ",i+1);
        char ftemp[10];
        char ltemp[10];
        int tempScore;

        scanf("%s %s %d", ftemp, ltemp, &tempScore);
        fname[i] = malloc(strlen(ftemp) + 1);
        lname[i] = malloc(strlen(ltemp) + 1);
        score[i] = malloc(sizeof(int));

        if(fname[i]==NULL||lname[i]==NULL||score[i]==NULL)
        {
            if(fname[i]!=NULL)
                  free(fname[i]);
            if(lname[i]!=NULL)
                  free(lname[i]);
            if(score[i]!=NULL)
                  free(score[i]);
            printf("Memory Error");
            exit(1);
        }
        else
        {
            strcpy(fname[i],ftemp);
            strcpy(lname[i],ltemp);
            *score[i]=tempScore;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++){
        printf("%s %s %d\n", fname[i], lname[i], *score[i]);
   }
}
```

Comment: I would very much prefer using local variables for the three pointers and only storing them when you're done. Makes the code much more readable.